# Wrong code in one step checkout

Tags: checkout, payment, code

[image: Extra code on the screen]

Does anybody know how to remove the unnecessary code on the checkout screen?(marked in yellow on the picture).

The code for this block is:

[image]

Hope somebody could help me, thanks!

Comment: Please provide specifics. Even if we can infer, note what step of the checkout this is (payment method I presume), what version of Magento you're using, and if you're using a custom checkout extension.

Comment: Also, this looks like a custom payment method, perhaps added by some extension -- that would be useful to note, but beware that support for specific extensions around here does not churn out positive feedback.

Comment: Thanks, It is a exstension for part payment invoice. Also its running on magento vs 1.7.0.2. .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the payment form block is calling `$this->htmlEscape()` on something that it shouldn't.

Assuming this is a payment method from an extension, and assuming it was written to properly extend from `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`, then you can find its block (and possibly template) by finding its model.

Example: `app/code/community/Klarna/Modulename/Model/Method/Paymentmethodname.php`

You would hopefully see some protected properties at the top, eg:

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'payment/form_paymentmethodname';
protected $_infoBlockType = 'payment/info_paymentmethodname';
```

The form block is an alias for:

`app/code/community/Klarna/Modulename/Block/Form/Paymentmethodname.php`

Open that up to hopefully see something this:

```
...
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('payment/form/paymentmethodname.phtml');
}
...
```

And there's your template. Open that template up and look for calls to `$this->htmlEscape()` on some price markup or block.

That's as close as I can get to helping you. Your question is unfortunately a bit too broad.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that and see:) (never been into that issue or plugin before, but it's worth a try:))

Comment: You're welcome. If it helps, here's a decent article on how payment methods are built in Magento: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method